# DateTimePicker - set background color IOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, datetimepicker

[image]

Im trying to use a DateTimePicker from the library '@react-native-community/datetimepicker' from within Expo - however I can't seem to change the background color from the light grey as pictured. Is it possible to do so on IoS ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can use the `style` prop, as can be seen in the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#style-optional-ios-only).

Something like so I would think:

```
<RNDateTimePicker style={{backgroundColor: "blue"}} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've already tried that and there is still some kind of grey shading to the DateTimePicker.